# NHibernate - Join 2 tables and search

Tags: c#, sql, nhibernate

I am trying to create SQL query for NHibernate:

SQL would look like this:

```
Select p.*
From PPoint p
Inner join PPFile f on p.ImportID = f.ImportID
where p.Name like '%a%'
Or p.Code like '%a%'
Or f.FileName like '%a%'
```

Can't find a decent example even sounds easy to do.

Currently I've got:

```
        var pointList = session
            .CreateCriteria(typeof(PPoint))
           .Add(Restrictions.Or(Restrictions.Or(Restrictions.Or(Restrictions.Or
                Restrictions.Like("Name", "%" + search + "%"),
                Restrictions.Like("Code", "%" + search + "%")),
                Restrictions.Like("Test", "%" + search + "%")),
                Restrictions.Like("Test2", "%" + search + "%")),
                Restrictions.Like("FileName", "%" + search + "%")))
            .List<PPoint>();
```

NHibernate version 2.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found solution:

```
var pointList = session
                .CreateCriteria(typeof(PPoint), "p")
                .CreateAlias("ImportFile", "f", NHibernate.SqlCommand.JoinType.InnerJoin)
                .Add(Restrictions.Disjunction()
                    .Add(Restrictions.Like("p.Name", search, MatchMode.Anywhere))
                    .Add(Restrictions.Like("p.Code", search, MatchMode.Anywhere))
                    .Add(Restrictions.Like("p.Test1", search, MatchMode.Anywhere))
                    .Add(Restrictions.Like("p.Test2", search, MatchMode.Anywhere))
                    .Add(Restrictions.Like("f.FileName", search, MatchMode.Anywhere)))
                .List<PPoint>();
```

Major thing is to describe relationship in mapping file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2"
                   assembly="AAA.Data"
                   namespace="AAA.Data.Domain">

  <class name="PPoint" lazy="true">
    <id name="PPointID" />
    <!--<property name="ImportID" />-->
    <many-to-one name="ImportFile" column="ImportID" not-null="true" cascade="all-delete-orphan" />

    <property name="Code" />
    <property name="Test1" />

    ...
  </class>
```

Comment: Cool that we've now got examples of solving the same problem using QueryOver and not. It gives us insight into how the QueryOver api evolved.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using nHibernate 3.0 or higher? This kind of query fits the [QueryOver API](http://nhforge.org/blogs/nhibernate/archive/2009/12/17/queryover-in-nh-3-0.aspx) quite well.

```
string searchString = string.Format("%{0}%", search);
PPoint ppointAlias = null;
PPFile ppFileAlias = null;
var pointList = session.QueryOver<PPoint>(() => ppointAlias)
                       .JoinQueryOver<PPFile>(ppPoint => ppPoint.ImportFile, () => ppFileAlias)
                       .Where(
                                 Restrictions.On(() => ppointAlias.Name).IsLike(searchString))
                                              ||
                                 Restrictions.On(() => ppointAlias.Code).IsLike(searchString))
                                              ||
                                 Restrictions.On(() => ppFileAlias.FileName).IsLike(searchString))
                              )
                        .List();
```

Comment: I use NHibernate 2.2 version.